# Visual Studio 2015 Community: ISLE ("Setup and Deployment" Doesn't Appear)

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I am following the tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384837.aspx).

Although, I am stuck on step 2 of **To install the ISLE setup and deployment project template**, where it says:

> and then select **Setup and Deployment**.

This option doesn't even appear for me. The only option available under "Other project types" is "Visual Studio Solutions". I have searched the web for a direct download instead of this, yet I found nothing.

Answer (score 16):

An InstallShield Software Engineer just answered this question in a [Flexera Software forum thread](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?219262-InstallShield-LE-2015-not-working-on-VS2015-Community-Edition&highlight=community+2015): "InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition does not support Visual Studio Community 2015." He refers to the ISLE registration page which reads: "InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio supports Visual Studio Professional, Premium and Ultimate editions."

This seems to be the (annoying) answer, although it contradicts Microsoft stating that "[InstallShield Limited Edition is free for users of all Visual Studio editions except the Express editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531020.aspx)" (and Community Edition is not the same as the Express editions!)

So, the alternatives seem to be:

- continue to use VS 2013 with ISLE
- or pay for VS Professional 2015 (or higher) to get ISLE
- or pay for InstallShield to use it within VS Community 2015
- or use a different setup and deployment tool (which probably means creating existing ISLE setup projects from scratch)

Answer (score 7):

This [download](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) seemed to give me an installer extension. It is not exactly what is mentioned in the tutorial link I provided in the question, but instead it provides the option of

> Visual Studio Installer

under

> Other Project Types

with a possible project selection of

> Setup Wizard

that essentially provides you a help wizard/tutorial throughout the process.

Comment: I have installed this on my Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, but I do not see `Visual Studio Installer` under `Other Project Types`. I have tried all frameworks. Does it only appear when within certain existing projects?

Comment: Visual Studio Installer is an Extension you can download from within V.S. The ISLE is something else.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that ISLE 2015 will not install in VS2015 Community.  However, it WILL install in VS2013 Community in conflict with their statement that ISLE (all editions implied) supports only VS Professional (all editions implied).  It is upsetting that Flexera chooses not to support VS2015 Community so I will cease using ISLE and find another installer to use.

Comment: While not a great answer, it does answer the question.

Comment: As I understood from their announcement it was available for all. But I had VS.2015 Community and the template did not appear. I had VS.2013 Ultiimate but I don't bother to use it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

This might be helping.. Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects

Comment: I can confirm this works great. Under Other Project Types you will see now Visual Studio Installer. From there you can select the Setup project.

Answer (score 1):

You could add Visual Studio Installer extension to Visual Studio Community 2015 by following the steps below. 
1. In Visual Studio Community 2015, click Tools -> Extension and Updates.
2. Click Online -> Visual Studio Gallery. In the search box at the top right corner, searching for Installer.
3. There should be an entry called "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Project". Click and follow its instruction to install it.
4. After installation, reopen Visual Studio Community 2015. When adding new project, the Visual Studio Installer should be shown in other project types.

[Installer Project in Visual Studio Community 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLBoN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go and Download This Package From [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects).

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2015 community does not have visual studio installer extension. You have to download it from the following link
[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects]